# How to handle log file with infinite loop using powershell?

Tags: powershell

I execute my script with infinite loop, and store the log. But It return this error

```
+ $Log = Start-Transcript -Path $Log_Path -Force
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Transcript], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotStartTranscription,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartTranscriptCommand
```

This is my code

```
for(;;)
{
# CONFIG FILE LOAD
#============================================#
[xml]$Config_File = Get-Content .\Config.xml

# LOG
#============================================#
$Log_Path = $Config_File.Automation_Config.Path.Log
$Log = Start-Transcript -Path $Log_Path -Force
Get-Date
Write-Host ">>Log_File: $Log"

######## DOING SOME PROCESS ########

}
```

Comment: Do a `Stop-Transcript` at the end of the loop. You can't start another transcript while there is still a transcript running.

Comment: also, this >>> `for(;;)` <<< is a truly odd way to do an infinite loop. [*grin*] a more PoSh-like bit of code would be something like `while ($True)` ...

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Well, it could be argued that both `for (;;) {...}` and `while ($true) {...}` are equally odd ways of expressing an infinite loop, since both are working around the lack of a `forever {...}`  construct in PowerShell.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - yep, it can be argued that way. still, `while ($True)` seems more obvious than the really rather odd looking `for (;;)` ... to me, at least. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

You can not `Start-Transcript` twice. 
Use `Stop-Transcript`.

If you are not sure if transcription is running, make an empty `try-catch`:

`try { Stop-Transcript -ErroAction Stop } catch { <# Do Nothing #> }`

Personally I use such `try-catch` construction at the beginning of the script when testing automatic scripts interactively and have to stop them manually in the middle.

**IMPORTANT:** `Write-Host` may be not logged using Transcript into log file on Windows 8, 8.1, 2012, 2012R2. Use `Write-Output` or [Read this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3014136) and install [KB3014136](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=3014136)